# Return the results of a resursive function

Tags: jquery

I have a recursive function and need to know when it's finished so I can return the latest results;

The let called results grows.

I need it to only return it once it finished growing.

Comment: I need the function to result the results though.

Comment: I'm not really sure I get it? Isn't it already returning when it's done? You just have the console.log inside the function, rather than logging the actual returned value -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/179ksdLa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const target= 10;
const list= [2, 5];
const zero = 0;
let results = [];

function test(amount, list, start, list) {
    let next_results = [];
    for (let i = start; i < collection.length; i++) {
      let left = amount - collection[i];
      let currentList = list.slice(zero);
      currentList.push(collection[i]);

      if (left < zero) return [];

      if (left === zero) {
          next_results.push(list2);
          results = results.concat(next_results);
          return results;
      } else {
          let newr = test(left, list2, i, collection);
          if (newr.length) {
              next_results = next_results.concat(newr);
          }
      }
    }
    return results;
}

//Start point
test(target, [], zero, list);
```

the results:

```
[ { Combinations: [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] },  { Combinations: [ 5, 5 ] } ]
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Your code works fine. Only issue is that the function doesnt return a response. I need the above function to return the results when its finished. So I could do a unit test on the function and it returns me the correct results for example.

Comment: You don't have to have that because `results` is defined outside those functions and its value will persist. But if you insist, I can modify the code to return one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea. the recursive function should return a value or under a certain condition call itself passing the value... the final product would be the end result after all recursive iterations

```
function recursive(v){
   if(condition) return recursive(v++);
   else return v;
}

var n = recursive(1);
```